# check connection to xml file for 404 Google Apps-Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I created a Google Doc add-on that connects to an xml file to read some data. No issues, but with Chromebooks, Google docs can be used offline, so obviously the connection fails. I want to catch any error on the  UrlFetchApp.fetch() method, but I don't see anything [on the API site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) . Here is my connection code:

```
 var url = 'http://XXXXXXX.xml';
 var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
 //how do I check the error here?
 var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
```

I tried checking xml for null, but that didn't work. I want to catch any error on the connection. I realize there is something that is easy here, but I am working outside my element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch the http responses, you have to use the [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) `fetch(url,params)` where the variable 'params' is a json containing different instructions. 
One of the parameters that you can send is called: muteHttpExceptions. This is a boolean value (true, false).

When setting it to 'true', the fetch will not throw an exception, rather it will give you the response with the failing code and message.

the code would look like:

```
var params =
   {
     "muteHttpExceptions": true
   };

   UrlFetchApp.fetch("url", params);
```